# Connect Android Virtual Device to IIS Express local

Tags: android, iis-express

I found many tutorial to permit external user to connect to IIS Express but none of them worked... Here's what I have :
My file applicationhost.config :
[image]

My code to access the local server :

```
private final String SERVER = "http://<my-pc-ip>:51234/Example/exemple";

protected String doInBackground(String... strJson ) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(SERVER);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(strJson[0]);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
        }
        else {
            response="NO HTTP_OK : " + responseCode;
        }
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        response = "malformedURL" + e.toString();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        response = "Protocol" + e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        response = "IOException" + e.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "Exception" + e.toString();
    }
    return response;
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

When I connect with : http://:51234/Example/example
I get : error 400 -- When I connect with : 10.0.2.2 I get : connection timed out -- When I connect with : localhost I get : Connection refused

I tried the command line (in administrator) : 
`netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:51234/ user=everyone`
But I get : `Échec de la création du SDDL ; erreur : 1789
 Paramètre incorrect.`

I'm running the server with visual studio 2017, and I can't touch the script on the server. Please guys help me I'm sooooo feed up with this problem !

**EDIT** : I succeeded at with the `netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:51234/ user=everyone` with "tout le monde" in place of "everyone"

I placed an INbound rule in my windows firewall to accept port 51234 but now I have an error 503 :(

**EDIT 2** : My error 503 was because I modified the wrong applicationhost.config. If you have Visual Studio 2017 applicationhost.config is in your project. When I edited the good one it worked instantly.

Comment: In which physicalPath are your scripts?

Comment: `My file applicationhost.config : ` Can you change that config file? And not the scripts?

Comment: `I get : error 400` Please realize what that means. And then tell us. What is the difference with `connection timed out ` ? Realize!

Comment: @greenapps Thank you for trying to help me (couldn't respond before sorry), I edited the solution I found. And yeah I know I wasn't making sense with my explanation but my situation is a bit complicated right now...

Comment: Maybe you should summarize what you learned as an answer and accept it. I do have a blog post with more technical details for your reference, https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3